# with nvidia optimus + xorg 1.19.3 + kernel 4.10.0-15 and still having screentearing

Tags: asus, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime, 17.04

I updated my ubuntu to zesty zapus beta 2 now, I have a laptop ASUS N552VW with optimus (NVIDIA GTX 960m + intel gpus) but I was expecting the screen tearing issue to dissapear with the latest xorg + nvidia drivers + kernel 4.10+

Actually I have only the NVIDIA card set via NVIDIA prime.

Any idea on how can I solve my screen tearing issue?

This has been driving me crazy for a while now.

My xorg.conf (by default, I haven't touched it yet)

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Thanks

Comment: anyone? please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this line:

```
options nvidia_381_drm modeset=1
```

In this file as root:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/zz-nvidia-modeset.conf
```

Replace '381' by your driver version that you will install.
Now uninstall and reinstall the driver.

Wait a few minutes after login. If it works, this command should return 'Y'

```
sudo cat /sys/module/nvidia_drm/parameters/modeset
```

Although I ***would not recommend using it now*** because it have some significant bugs. To turn on or off:

```
#on    
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --set 'PRIME Synchronization' '1'
#off
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --set 'PRIME Synchronization' '0'
```

[Reference](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/957814/linux/prime-and-prime-synchronization/1)

Comment: Life saver! I cant believe this! worked! 
Actually I didn't need to do the last step, I just added the line, reinstalled the driver and freaking worked! Life saver man.

Comment: Unfortunately I found unexpected freezes using it :(

Comment: UPDATE: with latests NVIDIA drivers (in my case 375.66) everything worked great so far :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following? https://freedompenguin.com/articles/quick-tips/nvidia-linux-video-game-tearing-fix/

Comment: I was expecting that the new driver + xorg would prevent me from doing that but anyway, I'll try today's night, and post the result here. Thank you

Comment: Nope, didn't work :(